# ¿Como correr una aplicación como servicio en Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows, servicio

Tengo la aplicación que quiero convertir en servicio de windows<sup>1</sup>, como un .exe , descargué srvstart.exe y luego en cmd he utilizado esta línea de código para crear el servicio:

```
SC CREATE MyAppName Nombre de pantalla = "MyAppName" binpath = "srvstart.exe MyAppName-c D: MyAppName_service.ini" start = auto
```

Luego un mensaje me indica que el proceso fue exitoso, para comprobar que el servicio exista utilizo el comando **start** como "start MyAppName" y me aparece que el sistema no puede encontrar el archivo.

El servicio creado aparece en la lista de servicios,  cuando intento correrlo manualmente con el click derecho, aparece una advertencia que dice que:

> Windows no puede encontrar el archivo.

---

<sup>1</sup> Sistema operativo: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Comment: Quizas en binpath tengas que poner la ruta completa del ejecutable, algo como C:\path\folder\srvstart.exe ...... Hace tiempo que no creo servicios, pero creo recordar que era así

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Por favor agrega la ubicación de la aplicación, además revisa la sintaxis; es posible que la ruta del programa no sea correcta.

Comment: Gracias por responder , en lugar del .ini coloqué directamente la ruta del .exe  , con el comando   "sc qc" pude ver en el cmd la configuración del servicio creado, es decir, aparentemente existe, y además sale en la lista de servicios, cuando lo quiero correr esta vez me dice que el tiempo de respuesta superó el time out, y no deja correrlo.  (ERROR 1053)